# Как удалить введенную строку

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
var s,t:string;
var k: integer;

begin
  readln(s);
  
  readln(t);
  
  for var i:=1 to length(s) do
  begin
    k:=pos(t,s);                                                                                                            
    delete(s,k,length(s));
    
  end;

  writeln(s);
  
end.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: допустим: вводится s , вводится t , t должно удалить указанное слово , например: ввод: asd adsksdk asd вывод: adsksdk

Comment: Все ещё непонятно. Приведите нормальный пример. Вводится две строки или что?

Comment: ввод: весело-весело встретим новый год .  вывод: - встретим новый год

Comment: а и еще в этом примере t := весело

Comment: Нужно удалить подстроку из строки или строку из списка строк?

Comment: подстроку надо удалить

Answer (score 0):

```
readln(s);
readln(t);
p := Pos(t, s);
while p > 0 do begin
  Delete(s, p, Length(t));
  p := Pos(t, s);
end;
```